# implementing comparator to sort list of strings

Tags: java, comparator

I have a list of strings which I would like to sort instead of by their lexicographic order- by their weight (number of times the word appears in the specifies URL / number of words in this URL).

the problem is with the methode "searchPrefix" that when I creat a new Comparator, it obviously doesn't recognize the fields of that class in which I use to calculate the weight.

things iv'e tried:
 1. using SortedMap and then there is no need to implement the Comparator, only that the instructions specifically note to implement the Comparator.
 2. using getters (also didn't work because i'm working within the class and the methode);
 3. implement the list as List> urlList = new ArrayList... also didn't work.

(The implementation of Comparator is what I would like to do)
how do I change it to work?

```
package il.ac.tau.cs.sw1.searchengine;

import java.util.*

public class MyWordIndex implements WordIndex {

    public SortedMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>> words;
    public HashMap<String, Integer> urls;

    public MyWordIndex() {
        this.words = new TreeMap<String, HashMap<String, Integer>>();;
        this.urls = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }

    @Override
    public void index(Collection<String> words, String strURL) {
        this.urls.put(strURL, words.size()); // to every page- how many words in it.
        String subPrefix = "";
        HashMap<String, Integer> help1; // how many times a word appears on that page
        for (String word : words) {
            if (word == null || word == "") // not a valid word
                continue;
            word.toLowerCase();
            help1 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
                subPrefix = word.substring(0, i);
                if (this.words.get(subPrefix) == null) { // new prefix
                    help1.put(strURL, 1);
                    this.words.put(subPrefix, help1);
                }
                else {  // prefix exists
                    if (this.words.get(subPrefix).get(strURL) == null)//new URL with old prefix
                        this.words.get(subPrefix).put(strURL, 1);
                    else                           // both url and prefix exists   
                        this.words.get(subPrefix).put(strURL, help1.get(strURL) + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List<String> searchPrefix(String prefix) {
        prefix.toLowerCase();
        List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (String word : this.words.keySet()) {
            if (word.startsWith(prefix)) {
                for (String strUrl : this.words.get(word).keySet()) {
                    urlList.add(strUrl);
                }
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(urlList, new Comparator<String>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(String strUrl1, String strUrl2) {
                Double d1 =  this.words.get(word).get(strUrl1) / this.urls.get(strUrl1);
                Double d2 =  this.words.get(word).get(strUrl2) / this.urls.get(strUrl2);
                return Double.compare(d1, d2);
            }
        });

        ........
    }
```

Comment: Are you trying to sort by lexicographic order or weight?

Comment: what is that word in sort method's comparator?

Comment: You can access the members of `MyWordIndex` from within the comparator body by writing `MyWordIndex.this` instead of just `this`. I'm very confused about what you're trying to do though, as there is no variable `word` in scope.

Comment: @pbabcdefp you are right, it was an editing problem, the last version didn't save. now it's OK.
I'll try what you suggested anyway.

Comment: You also need to cast one of the `int`s in each division to a `double`. `int / int` gives you `int`.

Comment: OK, but that's not the main problem, the main problem is that i can't reach the fields (after using MyWordIndex.this it can't find "word" because again, it's a different class.)

Comment: Can you post the class with the variable `word` in it?

Comment: `word` appears in the methode `searchPrefix` in `for (String word : this.words.keySet()) {`...

Answer (score 0):

These changes take you closer to a solution.

```
Double d1 =  MyWordIndex.this.words.get(word).get(strUrl1) / (double) MyWordIndex.this.urls.get(strUrl1);
Double d2 =  MyWordIndex.this.words.get(word).get(strUrl2) / (double) MyWordIndex.this.urls.get(strUrl2);
```

I don't know what `word` is supposed to be though as there is no variable with that name in scope.

Comment: 'word' is the loop variable in for loop before the comparator. Hence it can not be accessed in the comparator. OP needs to clarify what he wants the 'word' to be here?

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion for the for-loop in your index method:

```
for (int i = 1; i < word.length(); i++) { // no point starting at 0 - empty string
    subPrefix = word.substring(0, i);
    if (this.words.get(subPrefix) == null) { // new prefix
        help1.put(strURL, 1);
        this.words.put(subPrefix, help1);
    }
    else {  // prefix exists
        Integer count = this.words.get(subPrefix).get(strURL);
        if (count == null)//new URL with old prefix
            count = 0;
        this.words.get(subPrefix).put(strURL, count + 1);
    }
}
```

While we are on this, may I suggest [Guava multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) which does this sort of counting for you automatically:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Multiset;
import com.google.common.collect.HashMultiset;

public class MultiTest{

    public final Multiset<String> words;

    public MultiTest() {
        words = HashMultiset.create();
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        MultiTest test = new MultiTest();
        test.words.add("Mandible");
        test.words.add("Incredible");
        test.words.add("Commendable");
        test.words.add("Mandible");
        System.out.println(test.words.count("Mandible")); // 2
    }
}
```

Finally to solve your problem, this should work, haven't tested:

```
@Override
public List<String> searchPrefix(String prefix) {
    prefix = prefix.toLowerCase(); // Strings are immutable so this returns a new String
    Map<String, Double> urlList = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    for (String word : this.words.keySet()) {
        if (word.startsWith(prefix)) {
            for (String strUrl : this.words.get(word).keySet()) {
                Double v = urlList.get(strUrl);
                if (v == null) v = 0;
                urlList.put(strUrl, v + this.words.get(word).get(strUrl));
            }
        }
    }
    List<String> myUrls = new ArrayList<String>(urlList.keySet());
    Collections.sort(myUrls, new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String strUrl1, String strUrl2) {
            return Double.compare(urlList.get(strUrl1) / MyWordIndex.this.urls.get(strUrl1),
                                  urlList.get(strUrl2) / MyWordIndex.this.urls.get(strUrl2));
        }
    });

    return myUrls;
}
```